# FIFOs in C (Named-pipes)

Tags: c, named-pipes, fifo, mkfifo

I'm getting permission errors when trying to `mkfifo()` in the current directory. I definitely have permission to create files here. Any idea what the problem could be?

```
char dir[FILENAME_MAX];
getcwd(dir, sizeof(dir));


for(i = 0; i<num_nodes; i++)
{
    char path[FILENAME_MAX];
    sprintf(path, "%s/%d",dir, i);
    printf("%s\n", path);
    fifoArray[i] = mkfifo(path, O_WRONLY);
    if(fifoArray[i] < 0)
    {
         printf("Couldn't create fifo\n");
         perror(NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Couldn't create fifo" seems like an error message.  As such, it belongs on `stderr`.  It would be better to simply write `perror( path );`  Your printf is probably changing `errno`, so your call to perror is giving you bad information.

Comment: Have you checked what `errno` is set to?

Comment: remove the printf, what perror() print ?

Comment: what is the file system?

Comment: seems 2nd argument of mkfifo is not correct, pl. change the call to fifoArray[i] = mkfifo(path,S_IRWXU );

Answer (score 5):

You're creating it with an `oflag` not a `mode_t`.

[mkfifo](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo) takes a second parameter of type [mode_t](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/mode_005ft-Values.html)

In other words something like: `0666`. You're trying to feed it an `oflag` as defined in `fcntl.h`, this is normally like:

```
#define O_RDONLY             00
#define O_WRONLY             01
#define O_RDWR               02
```

Hence, `Invalid argument`. Here's a way to open the fifo:

```
char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";
mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

if((fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK)) < 0){
  printf("Couldn't open the FIFO for reading!\n");
  return 0;
}
else {
   //do stuff with the fifo
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are relying on the output of perror to tell you that you are getting permission errors, you are likely mistaken.  The call to printf is very likely changing errno, so that information is bogus.  Do not call printf.  Just write:

```
perror( path );
```

and see if the error messages change.